# How to append the string at a cursor position in a rich text box C#?

Tags: c#, append, richtextbox

I want to add string in rich text box at that position where the cursor is blinking. I also want to change the color of text that I entered. For example If there is pre-entered text which color is black, then I entered a new string then this string should have blue color. And it should be for all the time i entered the string. And the strings I entered, they should remain blue. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current cursor position is also know as the `SelectionStart`. Simply set the `SelectionStart=0` and then set all SelectionXXX properties you want to:

```
richtTextBox1.SelectionLength=0;
richtTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
```

Now all you type will be blue.

No more and no less is needed. No need to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event.

Note that if you move the cursor position to a different spot that spot will have a color of its own and when you enter new text there it will have that color.

If you want to apply the new color (Blue) to other spots you need to code the `SelectionChanged`  event maybe like this:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // you should check if there is no text selected
     // or else any selection will be colored immediately: 
     if ( richTextBox1.1.SelectionLength  == 0)
       richTextBox1.1.SelectionColor = yourNewColor; 
}
```

And as usual, if you want to color a portion that is already there with a new color you need to select that portion and again set the color. Best use a color palette for this! Using a few colored `Labels` you might write:

```
private void colorLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Color yourNewColor= ((sender) as Label).BackColor;
     richTextBox1.1.SelectionColor = yourNewColor; 
}
```

If you want to you can use the image of a richer palette in a `Panel's BackgroundImage` and code its `MouseClick` event:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Color c = ((Bitmap)panel1.BackgroundImage).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
    { 
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = c;
    }
    else  // pick new BackColor:
    { 
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this code it is inserting the data at my desired position but is not change the text color.

string insertText = Text;
            int selectionIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;


           
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionIndex ;
           richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, insertText);
           richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
          
           richTextBox1.SelectionColor=Color.Blue;

Comment: `richTextBox1.Text =` This is a mistake. Never change the Text property of a RTB with any formatting or else you will mess up the formatting. To insert text by code set the SelectionStart to the desired position, the SelectionLength = 0  and write SelectedText = yourNewText. - You need to be clear about what is happenjnig: User enter new text  OR user colors existing text OR code adds/inserts new text OR code re-colors text. You always need to use the SelectionColor = newColor but the prepartion will be different.

Comment: it is not changing the color. the code i used is :
string insertText = Text;
            int selectionIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;


           
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionIndex ;
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = insertText;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;

Comment: Wrong order: first set the color then the text!

Comment: thank you very much! its working nice as i needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to subscribe to the event where text is changing from the textbox, this will give you the text that has been entered up to the cursor.

Then it is a simple matter of just appending text to that as  statements, where you can apply different formatting, as described here:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/

Comment: Thanks, How would i use it for Rich Text Box?

Comment: Actually i want to create text editor just like Notepad etc.

Comment: Aah, that's a completely different question my friend. I guess you can do that with a  TextBlock, but I can't tell you if it's the right thing to do, or if there are other ways that are more optimal, sorry